# How to secure my Firebase App build with EmberFire

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-security, emberfire

I scratch my head for that  Firebase security works as i want. 
My app is build with Ember and so with EmberFire. So structure is determine by EmberFire.

My database structure is as follow :

```
conversations : {
    $conversation_id {
        messages {
            //message data
        }
        users {
            $user_id1 :true
            $user_id2 :true
        }
    }
}
```

What i want is that only users that are part of a conversation can see and write message in this conversation. I tried this rule without success :

```
"conversations" : {
    ".indexOn" : "notify",
    ".read" : "auth !== null && root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)", 
    ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
}
```

It seems that auth.uid can't be passed to hasChild. I also tried the following,  because my conversation id is the join of users id that participate to the conversation :

```
"conversations" : {
   ".indexOn" : "notify",
   "$conversation" : {
       ".read" : "auth !== null && ($conversation.beginsWith(auth.uid) || $conversation.endsWith(auth.uid))", 
       ".write": "auth !== null && ($conversation.beginsWith(auth.uid) || $conversation.endsWith(auth.uid))"
   }
}
```

With this rule, no one can see conversation because the "conversations" node does not have .read rule. But if i adds ".read : true" to the "conversations" node, due to top-bottom rules in Firebase,  all users can see all conversations.

Edit : The second rule has the same problem that the first. beginsWith() expects a string argument. And auth.uid can't be used
Any idea to solve my problem?

Edit : Add auth !== null before the rule,makes that the error beginsWith() expects a string argument get out. But both rules still does not  work.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the conversation id as a join of the user ids that participate in the conversation?

Comment: Yes. This is what i do. I dont if is a antipattern or not

Comment: Well, it would be a problem if you had multiple conversations with the same users involved.

Comment: Generally, you want to use the firebase id as it [guaranteed to be unique](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html)

Comment: Conversation id will be unique because it is generate between only to user that have unique id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first try was that you were using root, but should have been using $conversation. Root is a rule snapshot that references root of the firebase, whereas $conversation is a variable that holds the id of the conversation you are trying to read/write.

```
"conversations" : {
       ".indexOn" : "notify",
       "$conversation" : {
           ".read" : "auth !== null && root.child('conversations/'+$conversation+'/users').hasChild(auth.uid)", 
           ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('conversations/'+$conversation+'/users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
       }
    }
```